# Send notification from PHP application on Node.js chat event

Tags: php, node.js, communication

I'm using Node.js socket.io as chat server for my main project written in PHP.
All the logic of sending notifications or emails to users is in PHP project.
The issue is to send notification to user when something happens in Node.js chat.

I'm thinking to it with RabbitMQ, is it a right solution for this? Or maybe will be better to write some kind of API for PHP application and use it for this worker-like task?

Comment: In Nodejs there is Sockek.IO NPM is available use emit function where php function will post the message, PHP have socket library http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php ...what is the issue to send messages?

Comment: It's not really what I want.
It is inconvenient to use PHP socket as is (cause I should write a daemon manually to receive smth, but why if there is a lot of specified systems for that (RabbitMQ, Gearman), I'm just trying to know, is there is a right way to use AMPQ in this case.